# android lifecycle onActivityResult vs onStop

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

If activity A starts activity B for result, I was under the impression that the onStop method of activity B is called before the onActivityResult method of activity A. Why is that not the case? I just tested it with a static variable that is set in `B.onStop` but when I read it in `A.onActivityResult` the variable is till null.

Comment: Please point out in the documentation where your expected behavior is described.

Comment: "the onStop method of activity B is called before the onActivityResult method of activity A" - this is the default behavior and this is expected also. What's your opinion against it ?

Comment: @CommonsWare : well not everything needs to be documented. I imagine I must first leave activity B before returning to activity A. It only seems logical in that regard.

Comment: "well not everything needs to be documented" -- true, but you have not explained how you came to your "impression" otherwise. "I imagine I must first leave activity B before returning to activity A. It only seems logical in that regard." -- if the behavior is undocumented, taking guesses as to its behavior, and then complaining when those guesses are proven invalid, is illogical.

Comment: @CommonsWare so where is this discussion going? Do you have an explanation for why the behavior is the way it is? The OP seeks an explanation for the behavior. BTW I didn't guess: I tested and found the result counter-intuitive. So now I am asking if anyone understands why.

Comment: @KaidulIslamSazal are you saying my test result is incorrect? Have you tested this?

Comment: "Do you have an explanation for why the behavior is the way it is?" -- because that is the way the engineers who wrote the code wrote it. "I didn't guess" -- your impression was a guess. Your test proved that your guess was wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's one of these days, isn't it? Woke up on the wrong side of the bed ... surfing the net ... landed on SO ... pissed at people asking why ... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your impression is wrong, `onActivityResult` is called before `onResume` and the documentation for `onStop` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html in the table following the activity cycle diagram states

> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another **activity has been resumed and is covering this one**. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.

Thus `onResume` in A is called before `onStop` in B is called.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is call `onPause`, however, you don't want to do too much there. [Here is what the docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29):

> protected void onPause () Added in API level 1
>
> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going
>   into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to
>   onResume().
>
> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will
>   be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so
>   be sure to not do anything lengthy here.
>
> This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the
>   activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user
>   and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to
>   start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a
>   good place to do things like stop animations and other things that
>   consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the
>   next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are
>   exclusive access such as the camera.